# How to merge a image and a Gif in Python Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I got a partly transparent Image and a GIF.

I want to paste the Image on the GIF with PIL that I get an animated GIF as background with the static image in the foreground.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have to adjust this for your own specific images, but here is a starting point -

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
transparent_foreground = Image.open(...)
animated_gif = Image.open(...)

frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame.paste(transparent_foreground, mask=transparent_foreground)
    frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])
```